# How to change to risk neutral measure in a mean reversion process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, risk-neutral-measure

For example, in the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process do I just replace the drift term with the risk free rate, like in the GBM case?

Answer (score 2):

Risk neutral version of O-U process is apparently a simple GBM.
See explanation here, http://web.mit.edu/wangj/www/pap/LoWang95.pdf
specifically section II.

Comment: II.B: "Despite the differences between the trending 0-U process and an arithmetic Brownian motion, Grundy (1991) points out that both data-generating processes yield the same risk-neutralized price process (equation (5)) hence the Black-Scholes formula still applies to options on stocks with log-price dynamics given by equation (6)."